# APL - How can I find the longest word in a string vector?

Tags: functional-programming, apl, dyalog, gnu-apl

I want to find the longest word in a string vector. Using APL I know that the shape function will return the length of a string e.g.

```
⍴ 'string' ⍝ returns 6
```

The reduce function allows me to map diadic functions along a vector but since shape is monadic this will not work. How can I map the shape function in this case? For example:

If the vector is defined as:

```
lst ← 'this is a string'
```

I want to do this:

```
⍴'this' ⍴'is' ⍴'a' ⍴'string'
```

Comment: The "longest word" can be 2 or 3 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "typical" approach would be to treat it as a segmented (or: separated) string and prefix it with the separator *(a blank*) and pass it to a dfn for further analysis:

```
{}' ',lst
```

The fn then looks for the separator and uses it to build the vectors of words:

```
      {(⍵=' ')⊂⍵}' ',lst
┌─────┬───┬──┬───────┐
│ this│ is│ a│ string│
└─────┴───┴──┴───────┘
```

Let's remove the blanks:

```
      {1↓¨(⍵=' ')⊂⍵}' ',lst
┌────┬──┬─┬──────┐
│this│is│a│string│
└────┴──┴─┴──────┘
```

And then you "just" need to compute the length of each vector:

```
{1↓¨(⍵=' ')⊂⍵}' ',lst
```

This is a direct implementation of your request. However, if you're not interested in the substrings themselves but only the length of "non-blank segments", a more "APLy"-solution might be to work with booleans (usually most efficient):

```
      lst=' '
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So the ones are the positions of the separators - where do they occur?

```
      ⍸lst=' '
5 8 10
```

But we need a trailing blank, too - otherwise we're missing the end of text:

```
      ⍸' '=lst,' '
5 8 10 17
```

So these (`minus the positions of the preceeding blank`) should give the length of the segments:

```
      {¯1+⍵-0,¯1↓⍵}⍸' '=lst,' '
4 2 1 6
```

This is still somewhat naive and can be expressed in more advanced way - I leave that as an "exercise for the reader" ;-)

Comment: Thank you - hadn't thought of using the boolean method you described. Elegant!

Comment: Yes, booleans are so useful in APL - they can't be overestimated!

Comment: Or  just ≢¨(' '≠lst)⊆lst

Comment: Yes! But that's "advanced" ;-)

Comment: Nice - So just checked how @Paul Mansour's example works; (i) create a nested list of individual words; (ii) split the sentence into words using the binary output of (' '≠lst) then apply the tally function to each word. Thanks! This works too:  ⍴ ¨(' '≠lst)⊆lst

Comment: Indeed. Important to note that tally always returns a simple scalar, whereas shape (rho) returns a vector. So tally applied with each returns a simple vector, while shape applied with each returns a nested vector.

Comment: @Paul Mansour Ah ok! I would get a domain error if I tried to use the vector output as a scalar

Comment: `{¯1+⍵-0,¯1↓⍵}⍸` can be just `¯1-2-/⍸`

Answer (score 3):

While [MBaas has already thoroughly answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55515122/5306507), I thought it might be interesting to learn the idiomatic Dyalog "train" `≠⊆⊢` derived from [Paul Mansour's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55514234/apl-how-can-i-find-the-longest-word-in-a-string-vector#comment97737780_55515122). It forms a dyadic function which splits its right argument on occurrences of the left argument:

```
      Split ← ≠⊆⊢
      ' ' Split 'this is a string'
┌────┬──┬─┬──────┐
│this│is│a│string│
└────┴──┴─┴──────┘
```

You can extend this function train to do the whole job:

```
      SegmentLengths ← ≢¨Split
      ' ' SegmentLengths 'this is a string'
4 2 1 6
```

Or even combine the definitions in one go:

```
      SegmentLengths ← ≢¨≠⊆⊢
      ' ' SegmentLengths 'this is a string'
4 2 1 6
```

If you are used to the idiomatic expression `≠⊆⊢` then it may actually read clearer than any well-fitting name you can give for the function, so you might as well just use the expression in-line:

```
      ' ' (≢¨≠⊆⊢) 'this is a string'
4 2 1 6
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain. APL is cool!  !תודה רבה

Answer (score 0):

For how to find the longhest word in a string i would use, in NARS APL the function

```
f←{v/⍨k=⌈/k←≢¨v←(⍵≠' ')⊂⍵}
```

example to use

```
  f  'this is a string thesam'
string thesam
```

explenation

```
{v/⍨k=⌈/k←≢¨v←(⍵≠' ')⊂⍵}
            v←(⍵≠' ')⊂⍵  split the string where are the spaces and assign result to v
        k←≢¨v             to each element of v find the lenght, the result will be a vector
                          that has same lenght of v saved in k
      ⌈/k                 this find max in k
    k=                    and this for each element of k return 0 if it is not max, 1 if it is max
 v/⍨                      this return the element of v that are max
```